# Using DISTINCT in where clause subquery to find unique column combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I've been tasked with identifying and removing the duplicate entries from a really messy asset list. It's a mess because, over the years, different users / developers have tried to use alternate unique identification setups that, because of the absence of any primary keys, kind of worked if you weren't paying attention to the data.

I can find unique rows (in a broad sense) by using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    AssetId, AssetNo, PPH, Testdate
FROM dbo.AssetList;
```

And now I'm trying to expand the query to allow me to select every column in the dataset. I thought this would work:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.AssetList
WHERE AssetId IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        AssetId, AssetNo, PPH, Testdate
    FROM dbo.AssetList
);
```

But I was wrong. Can anyone explain to me how I can achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: Do a GROUP BY instead, and use HAVING to find duplicates.

Comment: How will you know which row to pull those extra values from?

Comment: As @jarlh says, `GROUP BY` with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` is the usual way to identify duplicates. But I suspect from your description, that your problem is subtly different. I am guessing that you have what may be termed quasi duplicates, in that two records are essentially duplicates, but differ in one or two non-essential fields. If the fields that in this sense don't matter are always the same, simply remove them from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`. If such fields vary, then we need sample data in order to help.

Comment: That's pretty much spot on, the catch with this asset list is that it's been compiled from x amount of data imports, some imports had more information in them than others but these 4 columns are present in every import so step 1 for me is to export the list of truly unique entries so that I'm only working with 11k records rather than 20k. After that though I think I'm going to have to do more manual work to remove the quasi duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Use [Row_Number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
        RN=ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (PARTITION BY AssetId, AssetNo, PPH, Testdate, add_more_columns
              ORDER BY  TestDate --or some other suitable column)
    FROM dbo.AssetList
) X
WHERE X.RN > 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.* FROM dbo.AssetList AS A
JOIN
(
   SELECT DISTINCT
   AssetId, AssetNo, PPH, Testdate
   FROM dbo.AssetList
)Q ON A.AssetId =Q.AssetId
```

Not sure what you want to achieve,but please try the above